# Passing instance variable between methods in same controller not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a multi stage form I'm trying to process.  One of the later stages needs to use data set by a previous stage.  I had thought that by setting the data I need in an instance variable, e.g.

```
@gateway = importer.get_gateway
```

I could then access it in a different controller method of the same controller class, e.g.

```
Rails.logger.info "populate_devices : gateway is #{@gateway}"
```

However in the logs `@gateway` is `nil` in this next step of the form submission.  Should it be working, or is this not the correct way to pass data from one controller method to another in the same controller class?  `@gateway` is definitely being set to not `nil` in the previous step as I display some of it's fields on the UI and have logged it.

Comment: I think you should store it in `session` , because Rails is a stateless technology .

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to storing data in the session, e.g. any size limitations?

Comment: There are , but only if you choose to use a cookies session store - up to 4k. If you decide to use ActiveRecords session store or memcache , there are no limits . They are easy to implement and fast .

Comment: Nutshell: controllers are instantiated per-request; instance variables do not persist across requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should store it in session, because Rails is a stateless technology. There are limitations in size, but only if you choose to use a cookie session store (up to 4k).

If you decide to use the ActiveRecord session store or memcached store, there are no limits. They are easy to implement and fast.

Comment: For something like this (state based workflow), it may make sense to put the current state in the database, attached to the current user object, or whatever you have along those lines

Comment: I agree with @JimDeville, something like memcache, Redis, AR… etc would be my choice before a cookie.

Comment: Thanks everyone, did not know controllers where created per request, makes perfect sense now.

Comment: It should be noted that the only real reason Rails is stateless is that HTTP is stateless.